# Building dynamic PDO Mysql Query

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm attempting to filter a list of results using the three following options:

Main Category, Subcategory and Search

Where the two category options are drop down lists and the search is a text box.

Here is my code so far:

**files.php**

```
    if (!isset($_GET['filter'])){
        $_GET['filter'] = "";
    }
    if (!isset($_GET['search'])){
        $_GET['search'] = "";
    }
    if (!isset($_GET['subcategory'])){
        $_GET['subcategory'] = "";
    }
```

// The form to filter the results:

```
<form method="get">
Category: <select name="filter">
    <option <?php if(!isset($_GET['filter'])){echo 'selected';} ?> value="">-- Select Category --</option>
    <option <?php if($_GET['filter'] == "1") {echo 'selected';} ?> value="1">View Vehicles Only</option>
    <option <?php if($_GET['filter'] == "2") {echo 'selected';} ?> value="2">View Lighting Equiptment</option>
</select><br /><br />
<?php 


        if(isset($_GET['filter'])){
            if($_GET['filter'] != ""){
                echo 'SubCategory:  <select name="subcategory">';
                    $sub_categories = getsubcategories($_GET['filter']);
                    foreach ($sub_categories as $cat){
                        echo '<option value = "'.$cat['cat_id'].'">'.$cat['cat_name'].'</option>';
                    }
                echo '</select><br /><br />';
            }
        }

    ?>
    Search Files: <input type="text" name="search" <?php if(isset($_GET['search'])){echo 'value="'.$_GET['search'].'"';}?> placeholder=" Enter a search term..." />
    <br /><br /><center><input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Update Results"/> <a href="files.php" class="btn btn-default">Reset Filters</a></center>
    </form>
```

// Calling the function to retrieve the results:

```
$files = getbycategory($_GET['filter'], $_GET['search'], $_GET['subcategory']);
```

// Looping through the results:

```
foreach($files as $file){

echo'<div class="col-lg-" id="file-'.$file['part_id'].'">
        <div class="file-list-item first" id="">';
            if ($file['image_url'] == "")
            {
                echo '<img class="file-image" height="120px" width="180px" src="'.baseurl.'/resources/img/no-image.png" />';
            } else {
                echo '<img class="file-image" height="120px" width="180px" src="'.$file['image_url'].'" />';
            }   

            echo '
            <div class="file-text">
                <h3><strong>'.$file['part_name'].'</strong></h3>
                Submitted by: '.$file['submitter'].'<br/>
                Author: '.$file['author'].'<br />
                Category: '.ucfirst($file['subcategory']).'<br />
                Description: '.substr($file['description'],0,45).'...
            </div>
            <div class="download">
                <a target="_blank" href="'.$file['download_url'].'" class="btn-success btn btn-default">Download</a>
                <a href="'.baseurl.'/broken.php?id='.$file['part_id'].'" class="btn btn-default">Report as Broken</a><br /><br />';
                    if($file['is_broken']){
                        echo '<span class="broken"><i data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left" id="broken" title="This file has been reported as broken by \'Alcon H\' and is awaiting review." class="fa fa-warning fa-2x"></i></span>';
                    }


                echo '

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>';
};
```

**file_functions.php**

// This is the function that retrieves the results:

```
function getbycategory($category, $search, $subcategory){

    global $db;

    $sm = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM parts WHERE main_category = :category AND active = 1 AND subcategory = :subcategory AND part_name LIKE :search");

        if ($category == ""){
            $category = '%';
            $sm->bindParam(":category", $category, PDO::PARAM_STR);    
        } else {
            $sm->bindParam(":category", $category, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        }

        if ($subcategory ==""){
            $subcategory = '%';
            $sm->bindParam(":subcategory", $subcategory, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        } else {
            $sm->bindParam(":subcategory", $subcategory, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        }

        if ($search == ""){
        $search = '%'.$search.'%';
        } else {
        $sm->bindParam(":search", $search, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        }

    $sm->execute();
    return $sm->fetchAll();
    }
```

The error that I am receiving is:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens' in /var/www/html/partsdb/resources/file_functions.php:74\nStack trace:\n#0 /var/www/html/partsdb/resources/file_functions.php(74): PDOStatement->execute()\n#1 /var/www/html/partsdb/files.php(18): getbycategory('', '', '')\n#2 {main}\n  thrown in /var/www/html/partsdb/resources/file_functions.php on line 74, referer: http://localhost/partsdb/files.php
```

Line 74 of file_functions.php is just where it is executed.

Can anyone see where I am going wrong?

Comment: Is it possible one of the params is null? I don't think that would matter but I'd be curious. Also - what happens if you remove all the if/then calls and just force in some (working) values?

Comment: I just commented out the contents of the function and replaced with var dumps for all of the variables and the result is string(0) "" string(0) "" string(0) "". This is expected though as when the page is first loaded no filters have been applied. I will try forcing values now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First use [**Ternary operator**](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) with `isset()`.

```
$category = isset($_GET["category"]) ? $_GET["category"] : "";
```

Declare an array to hold parameters.

```
$params = array();
```

Then set the stub of query into variable.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM parts ";
```

Set a flag to 0 to switch from WHERE to AND for 2 or more parameters

Start building the rest of your query incrementing `$flag` adding parameters to `$params` array

```
if($category != ""){
        $sql .= " WHERE main_category = ?";
        $params[] = $category;
        $flag++; 
        }
```

If flag > 0 use AND instead of WHERE

```
if($search != ""){
       if($flag > 0){
            $sql .= " AND search = ?";

       }else{
            $sql .= " WHERE search = ?";
       }
       $params[] =$search;
       $flag++;
```

Use "lazy" binding passing data into execute.

```
$sm->execute($params);
```

The final code.

```
<?php
$category = isset($_GET["category"]) ? $_GET["category"] : "";
$search = isset($_GET['search']) ? $_GET['search'] : "";
$subcategory = isset($_GET['subcategory']) ? $_GET['subcategory'] : "";
$params = array();

function getbycategory($category, $search, $subcategory){


    global $db;
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM parts ";
    $flag = 0;
    if($category != ""){
        $sql .= " WHERE main_category = ?";
        $params[] = $category;
        $flag++; 
        }
    if($search != ""){
       if($flag > 0){
            $sql .= " AND search = ?";

       }else{
            $sql .= " WHERE search = ?";
       }
       $params[] =$search;
       $flag++;
        }   
    if($subcategory != ""){
       if($flag > 0){
            $sql .= " AND subcategory = ?";

       }else{
            $sql .= " WHERE subcategory = ?";
       }
       $params[] = $subcategory;
       }   

    echo   $sql; //Remove after testing  
    print_r($params);//Remove after testing     
    $sm = $db->prepare($sql);  
    $sm->execute($params);
    return $sm->fetchAll();
}   
getbycategory($category, $search, $subcategory);



    }
```

Reading your code I see `$category = '%';` If you require `LIKE` instead of `=` you require to prepare FULL literal first.

```
$category = "%$category%";
```

Answer (score 1):

If this only happens when your search string is null, that is because:

```
    if ($search == ""){
        $search = '%'.$search.'%';
    } else {
        $sm->bindParam(":search", $search, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    }
```

only binds the parameter if the `$search` variable is not an empty string. To fix that you could modify it as:

```
    if ($search == ""){
        $search = '%'.$search.'%';
    } 

    $sm->bindParam(":search", $search, PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

so that it always binds the prepared statement with the search field. Although if empty $search will be replaced with string `%%` hence only returning values equal to string `%%` which seems a bit odd, as i believe you would prefer a `LIKE` statement there, although that is a different issue than this.